# Burninate the [comments] tag?

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

The [comments](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comments) tag has only been used once to ask a question about social networks comments for botnet C&C. I can't think of a reason why comments should have their own tag. Since comments are basically just text, links and pictures uploaded to a website and that can be seen by multiple users, any attack involving comments is either spam/phishing or it exploits some vulnerability of that Web platform.

Can we burninate the [comments](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comments) tag?

Comment: If it's just used once, I don't think you need to raise the issue on meta, since you can just edit the question accordingly and the tag will disappear.

Comment: I agree with @Arminius. I see someone has already removed the tag from the only question that had it, so the GC will delete the tag within a day. If it keeps being respawned by users, we can consider asking mods to blacklist it.

Comment: Also, Darwin, I am happy someone else joins the kill-useless-tags-crusade! :-)